# Necklaces and the generating function for inversions

Tags: co.combinatorics, gr.group-theory, symmetric-groups

The problem of Necklaces is well-known, i.e "The number of fixed necklaces of length $n$  composed of $a$ types of beads $N(n,a)$" can be calculated:
http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Necklace.html

Let us consider the limit $\lim_{n\to \infty}\prod_{p=1}^n N(p,a)$.
It is possible to show that the limit presents the result which looks like the generating function for inversion ( we may exclude one unimportant factor):
$\frac {a^n} {n!}$ $\prod_{p=1}^n \frac {1-a^p} {1-a}$

For $n \to \infty$ we have $\prod_{p=1}^n N(p,a) \approx \frac {a^n} {n!}$ $\prod_{p=1}^n \frac {1-a^p} {1-a}$. Then, for eg please see theorem #1
http://www.cs.uwaterloo.ca/journals/JIS/VOL4/MARGOLIUS/inversions.pdf
The generating function under theorem 1 looks like $\prod_{p=1}^n \frac {1-a^p} {1-a}$

So, a question appears, how to explain the influence of the symmetric group's properties for the particular case?
In other words why and how the connection appears?

Comment: Can you be more precise about the value of the limit? 

Comment: @Qiaochu Yuan Thank you, I've added the approximation of the limit

Comment: I don't understand how this limit is equal to the claimed generating function. Can you elaborate?

Comment: @ Gjergji Zaimi For $n \to \infty$ we have $\prod_{p=1}^n N(p,a) \approx \frac {a^n} {n!}$ $\prod_{p=1}^n \frac {1-a^p} {1-a}$. Then, for eg  please see theorem #1:http://www.cs.uwaterloo.ca/journals/JIS/VOL4/MARGOLIUS/inversions.pdf


Comment: The coefficient of $a^n/n!$ in $\prod N(p,a)$ is $\prod \varphi(p)$, but in the other side it is 1...

Comment: Also posted to m.se, without notice at either site; http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/178526/generating-function-for-inversion-and-necklace

Comment: @Gerry Myerson Sorry, I deleted it and the account as well ( I failed to recover my account).