# Geometric interpretation of table with permutations and inversions

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, mg.metric-geometry, mathematical-philosophy, symmetric-groups, physics

Let $T(n,k)$ is the number of permutations of numbers $1, ..., n$ and each of the permutations has $k$ inversions. We can consider a table for $T(n,k)$ for some $n$ and $k$. For eg.
$n=1,...,6$, $k=1,...,15$:

$1;$

$1, 1;$

$1, 2, 2, 1;$

$1, 3, 5, 6, 5, 3, 1;$

$1, 4, 9, 15, 20, 22, 20, 15, 9, 4, 1;$

$1, 5, 14, 29, 49, 71, 90, 101, 101, 90, 71, 49, 29, 14, 5, 1;$

If we look at numbers $1, 2, 6, 22, 101$ and so on, we can see the [structure](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/46368/the-property-of-kendall-mann-numbers) like $n-1/2$.
I am trying to find other similar structures in the table and very hope that there is a way to get a geometric interpetation. In other words how geometries can help here?

I find the question is intresting due to some physics interpretation. 
For instance,

1) $n+1/2$ - structure for quantum harmonic oscillator,

2) [Triangular numbers](http://oeis.org/A000217): $a(n) = C(n+1,2) = n(n+1)/2 = 0+1+2+...+n.$ form the number of levels with energy $n+1/2+1=n+3/2$ (in units of h*f0, with Planck's constant h and the oscillator frequency f0) of the three dimensional isotropic harmonic quantum oscillator.

3) The similar family of permutations have arisen in the study of [squeezed states](http://oeis.org/A186491)
of the simple harmonic oscillator.
The $n+1/2$ properties is connected to [symmetry](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/103716/necklaces-and-the-generating-function-for-inversions). It looks like there is a universal property. This is why any approaches to undersand it are very vital.

Comment: The numbers you described are know http://oeis.org/A000140. But what is the question? (As of now it sound open-ended.)

Comment: Piotr Migdal: Thank you. A few years ago the $n+1/2$ property of $T(n,k)$ was found just by pure accident ( I would say). I hoped to find something similar else via a geometry approach, but failed. Moreover, the generation function for inversion and formula for Products of necklaces (one of my other questions at MO) seems to be connected. So, I am trying to understand why it happens?

Comment: Piotr Migdal: Why the $n+1/2$ appears in physics and what is behind it if we would apply the property of numbers to quantum physics models (or extend the model).